# How zend framework avoid html <id> duplication?

Tags: html, css, zend-framework

How zend framework avoid html  duplication?

Example of html id duplication:

```
<div id="edit-form">first div</div>

<div id="edit-form">second div</div>
```

**Case1: page that user can add same forms/subform/etc.. by himself**

controller action example:

```
function indexMyAction(){
$form1=new MyForm();
$form2=new MyForm();
$form3=new MyForm(); 
$this->view->form1=$form1;
$this->view->form2=$form2; 
$this->view->form3=$form3; 
}
```

**Case2: manually defined html `<id>` by programmer - by which rule should be done to avoid duplication?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : the framework doesn't do this kind of checks.

So either you implement them yourself, or you make sure you use unique IDs by adding some sort of UUID to the IDs you define as a programmer.

Comment: I give new example in my question in case that framework should do that when created  3 forms  in action